# Many to Many relationships-Grouping

Tags: database, db2

I have one tables with list of PRODUCT1 and PRODUCT2.
What I would like to do is bundle or group all of the PRODUCT1 and PRODUCT2 in table , which have relationship/matching to a PRODUCT1 or PRODUCT2 in the table and vise versa.

**Input:**

```
PRODUCT1    PRODUCT2
00000AE503  00000Y2766
00000AE503  00000FG959
00000AE503  00000AE644
00000Y2766  00000AE503
00000Y2766  00000AE644
00000Y2766  00000FG959
00000FG959  00000Y2766
00000FG959  00000AE503
00000FG959  00000AE644
00000AE644  00000Y2766
00000AE644  00000FG959
00000AE644  00000AE503

00000AG744  00090Y3534
00000AG744  00090Y3533
00090Y3534  00000AG744
00090Y3534  00090Y3533
00090Y3533  00090Y3534
00090Y3533  00000AG744
```

**Output:**

```
PRODUCT1    PRODUCT2    GROUP
00000AE503  00000Y2766  1
00000AE503  00000FG959  1
00000AE503  00000AE644  1
00000Y2766  00000AE503  1
00000Y2766  00000AE644  1
00000Y2766  00000FG959  1
00000FG959  00000Y2766  1
00000FG959  00000AE503  1
00000FG959  00000AE644  1
00000AE644  00000Y2766  1
00000AE644  00000FG959  1
00000AE644  00000AE503  1

00000AG744  00090Y3534  2
00000AG744  00090Y3533  2
00090Y3534  00000AG744  2
00090Y3534  00090Y3533  2
00090Y3533  00090Y3534  2
00090Y3533  00000AG744  2
```

---

***Simplified Question***

```
RECORD       PRODUCT1    PRODUCT2    GROUP
 1          00000AE503  00000Y2766      1
 2          00000AE503  00000FG959      1                                           
 3          00000AG744  00090Y3534      2
```

If we look above three records,first record arrives we can directly assign group as 1,and for the second record we need to check the with first record,if any of the PRODUCT or PRODUCT1 matching then we need to park in the same group.. otherwise we need to create different group..EX like

```
record2.PRODUCT1=record1.PRODUCT1 or record2.PRODUCT1=record1.PRODUCT2
record2.PRODUCT2=record1.PRODUCT1 or record2.PRODUCT2=record1.PRODUCT1
```

Comment: Please simplify your example.

Comment: Or at least elaborate on how this output is produced (logically)

Comment: You can create a group fairly easily using a recursive query (check out the many questions on parent-child relationships to get the idea), but identifying *all* of the groups is a tricky problem, because there is no way of knowing ahead of time that two groups will not overlap.  This is a very interesting problem to solve in SQL.

Comment: @dan1111 - as well as being cyclical, in this case.  Mike - this would be a lot easier if you had everything in the same direction (remove the cycle).

Comment: Dan,Can you provide some sample code to look pls

Comment: Can somebody help to provide some ideas pls